# Uploadify IO error #2038 random on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, uploadify, ioerror

I've installed Uploadify to upload files on my server but it appears that with Google Chrome, there are random IO errors, even with small files.

On Firefox it works great.

Anyone has an idea of what it could be ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is linked with the last flash 10.2 version on Mac OS X

http://slideshowpro.net/news/archive/2011/02/file-upload-problem-with-slideshowpro-director-os-x-and-flash-player-10-2.php/

Comment: Ok, so its just on Mac. Thank you for this comment!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here : http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/7097/uploadify-io-error-2038-random-on-google-chrome (its the Flash plug-in shipped with chrome)