# Uploadify suddenly stopped working completely in Chrome 10

Tags: flash, google-chrome, uploadify

I'm using Uploadify to allow for multi file uploading in my web application. It has always worked across IE 7,8, 9, FF 3.6, Safari and Chrome.

Today I discovered by accident that it was working in each browser yet not in Chrome. I'm currently on Chrome 10.0.648.82 beta. The issue there is that I can select files to upload, yet after that nothing happens. I put alerts in all Uploadify events and non get fired. Then I went to the official demo site:

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

...and discovered that it does not work for Chrome there anymore either. I am running Chrome as default as can be, so it updated to this version itself. I have all default settings intact and no popup-blockers, ad blockers or any other add-in installed. I tried to debug using HTTP Fiddler, only to conclude no HTTP request is made at all after selecting files to upload.

Does anybody knows what is going on? Is this a Chrome issue or Flash issue? Are there any known resolutions?

PS: I am on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree, I think it is a Chrome or Flash issue (since Google ship Flash inside Chrome).

The uploadify demo page is working for me in Chrome 12.0.725.0 (which is the [current dev release](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Release_history)). You could try [switching to the dev or beta channel](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel#TOC-Subscribing-to-a-channel) to see if the issue is fixed for you.

Also, I found this other question that could help - [Uploadify IO error #2038 random on Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005632/uploadify-io-error-2038-random-on-google-chrome)

Comment: I'm using an older version of Uploadify and will first try to switch to the new one. If it then still does not work, I will wait for these new Chrome releases to become stable, it's all we can do. I'll give you the bounty, as I don't see any better answers arriving. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since it just broke with the new Chrome beta, I am 99% sure it's a Chrome issue. It works for me in v9 of Chrome.
I see you have posted in the support forum of the plugin, so let's see what the developers have to say on the issue.

Comment: It looks like the forum is completely ignored and full of spam responses.

Comment: True. Is there any other way to contact the developer of the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Double check Servlet,that is called by Uploadify and Filter classes if they exist.
Possibly it a matter of cookies handling,that are handled specifically by Chrome plus by Flash.
Flash doesn't set cookies(`jsessionid`).

Check this:[cookies in Flash](http://request.getattribute.com/2009/09/14/17/)

And this(my problem with Uploadify,especially last comments to answer):
[Uploadify plugin doesn't call Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272160/uploadify-plugin-doesnt-call-java-servlet)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see what this has to do with servlets. The issue appears before any back-end script starts. It is a client-side problem.