# Uploadify not working in Google Chrome and Safari

Tags: flash, browser, sugarcrm, uploadify, suitecrm

I have gone through all the available post on SO. But, couldn't found the helpful post. It was working fine earlier on all the browser. But, stop working now on Chrome and Safari. I do not get any error in console when loading it on Chrome and Safari.

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Any clue or suggestion to fix ?

```
IE      : 11.0.9600
Chrome  : 59
Safari  : 10.0.1
Firefox : 52.2.1esr
```

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042698/uploadify-suddenly-stopped-working-completely-in-chrome-10 and this one also https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/FDgP20bvgw8

Answer (score 9):

I got the same error. Even worse, I tried purchasing the HTML5 version, payed for it and never received the download link.
The workaround that I found (Chrome), is editing `Chrome preferences`, Search "`Flash`", and in the lower end of the form, add your site as an exception.

```
chrome://settings/content/flash?search=flash
```

Of course it isn't an acceptable solution for public websites or for open systems with hundreds of users, but at least is something to get the flash button to show again instead of the plain input element with no behavior that it started showing.

Comment: Anecdotally, working on an admin panel I built which uses uploadify, had the same problem. Chrome was set to "Ask First" for flash content, but didn't do so. Changing the allowed sites fixed it.

Comment: Thank you have saved my days. I have done all thing set except enable flash setting for specific website. Thanks you so much for solution

Answer (score 3):

This is related to flash setting for browser. As free version is flash based so flash should be working in browser. Please complete steps in this link: https://support.digication.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003963468-Enabling-Flash-for-Google-Chrome-Windows-Macintosh-

I am using HTML5 version and it is working in any browser.

Comment: Thank you have saved my days. I have done all thing set except enable flash setting for specific website. Thanks you so much for solution